# How do I import setup colyseus with a svelte app?

Tags: svelte, rollup, colyseus

I'm trying to start a [colyseus](https://www.colyseus.io/) app using Svelte.

I am import colyseus using:

```
import { Client } from 'colyseus.js'
```

This builds fine but gives me the following messages when running the app:

```
Creating a browser bundle that depends on "https", "http" and "url". You might need to include https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node

- @colyseus/schema

LiveReload enabled
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
https (guessing 'https')
http (guessing 'http$1')
url (guessing 'url')
```

In the browser the app crashes with this console message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: https is not defined
    at main.js:8:2
```

I've tried to setup the `rollup-plugin-polyfill-node` referenced in the log but this doesn't fix the issue

I'm also a newbie with Svelte/rollup etc so a simple explanation of what I am doing wrong would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colyseus.js (the client library) can not be run in a server environment, therefore you want to dynamically import Colyseus.js and run the setup code only after the component/page has mounted, and only in the browser environment.

Assuming this is a SvelteKit app, the following script (in a page or component) should work:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { browser } from '$app/env';

    async function connect() {
        let Colyseus = await import("colyseus.js");
        let client = new Colyseus.Client('ws://localhost:2567'); // or whereever your colyseus server instance is
        let room = await client.joinOrCreate("roomname", { /* options */ });
        // good to go
    }

    onMount(() => {
        if(browser) connect();
    })
</script>
```

The key is to conditionally dynamically import Colyseus. A regular import would also import it on the server.